# How can I count the number of times a value reoccurs within the same array?

Tags: c#, arrays, nested-loops

As the title says, I'm trying to count the number of times a value reoccurs within the same array. So, for example, if there was an array with the values 1, 1, 2, 2, the output would look something like: Value (1) occurred (2) times \n Value (2) occurred (2) times. Here's what I have so far:

```
foreach (var i in anArray)
{
    foreach (var m in secondArray)
    {
        if (i == m)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nValue " + i + " occurred " + count + " times"); 
}
```

I created a copy of the first array(secondArray) and am trying to make due comparing the arrays, but something is not right. The nested loop counts my values twice. So, where it would say: value (1) occurred (2) times, the next readout says: value (1) occurred (4) times, instead of moving on to the next value that's not (1). I realize it's counting the second (1) and adding the previous count to it...least I think I realize. How can I get around this only using arrays and no lists?

Comment: Complexity of O(n^2) is a bit unfortunate.

Comment: why did you make a second array?

Comment: What is the nature of numbers in the array.. can they be arbitrarily large? of they tend to be small - for example, below certain small number? can the numbers in the array be -ve? How big can be the array? is it ok to use additional memory to get the answer? Is performance of the algorithm any concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current design, you can just set count up front:

```
foreach (var i in anArray)
{
    count = 0; // Initialize each loop
    foreach (var m in secondArray)
    {
        if (i == m)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nValue " + i + " occurred " + count + " times"); 
}
```

That being said, you could build a dictionary from the second array, and use that:

```
var dict = secondArray.GroupBy(v => v).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
foreach(var i in anArray)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey[i])
        Console.WriteLine("\nValue " + i + " occurred " + dict[i] + " times"); 
    else
        Console.WriteLine("\nValue " + i + " occurred 0 times"); 
}
```

Comment: That looks like that could work. I'll have to get my code back in order before I can test it out. I still think instead of just displaying: "Value (1) occurred (2) times" once, it's going to jump to the next (1) in the array and display that string again...that goes for each repeating value. How can I make it to where it displays the count once for each repeating value?

Comment: @BenignBaboon If `anArray` has repeats, just do `foreach(var i in anArray.Distinct()) {` ...

Comment: Thank you very much. It works and now I have a new tool in my toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq

```
var counts = anArray.Concat(secondArray)
   .GroupBy(x => x)
   .Select(g => new { Number = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

foreach(var c in counts)
{
     Console.WriteLine("\nValue " + c.Number + " occurred " + c.Count + " times"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using a group by,  you can make it a one liner to display the occurances...

```
 anArray.GroupBy(a => a).ToList()
     .ForEach(g => Console.WriteLine("Value {0} occurs {1} times", g.Key, g.Count()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version:

```
foreach (var distinctItem in anArray.Distinct())
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nValue '{0}' occurred '{1}' times.", distinctItem,
        anArray.Count(i => i == distinctItem));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add system.linq name space to your class and then:

```
 var result = l.GroupBy(a => a).Select(s => new {Key= s.Key ,Counter= s.Count()});
  foreach (var item in result)
     Console.WriteLine("Value {0} occurred {1} times",item.Key,item.Counter);
```